# Multiple broker machine rabbitmq configuration, how does HA work?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to figure out how HA works. (high availability queues)

The current configuration I have is: every machine has multiple celery workers and points to itself as broker. Each machine can do this rather than point at one broker machine because of HA; in this way, there is less load on any one machine, as all are brokers and have copies of the same queue.

My question is, is my above logic correct? Or do all workers need to point to one broker machine regardless of HA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have looked at [HA](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) and [clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and have ensured that the queues mirror each other then what you are doing should be fine. But that may seem a tad inefficient to run it on every server where you run your workers.

The other option is to run your queues on a few servers for HA and have other servers running the workers to point to them. But since the celery worker config can only point to one broker url, you would need to work around that by possibly using a load balancer to which all workers will point to. This is to the best of what I've come to understand over the past few years on RabbitMQ HA for celery.

Comment: Yes I was thinking it would slow down the application very much if every server had a replicated queue, but I did not know by how big the slow down would be. The fact that the celery worker config can only point to one broker url has been the main challenge I've been facing. I've read in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/i87kIvHn6gg that the BROKER_URL can be a list of brokers (second to last response in link), but haven't been able to work it out. Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Also, is there a way to tell if a node is an HA node from rabbitmqctl (or another method)?

Comment: @jeffrey, the last time I had seen that thread, the response from @asksol about multiple brokers was not there. I was referring to the OP's observation about using a load balancer. I have not tried the approach of listing multiple urls for BROKER_URL. I will and post back here if I can get it to work. It would be interesting to know how the worker chooses which of the brokers to use. `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` gives the nodes in the cluster. Does that answer your question on how to tell if a node is an HA node? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks ksrini, I tried the list method myself, but I couldn't get it to work. rabbitmqctl cluster_status gives all the nodes in the cluster and also tells which are ram or disc, but has no information about which nodes are HA nodes. I'm trying to find out which node is a HA node from one of my servers so it can pick which node to connect to (it has to be a HA node!)